# mediaelement.js - How to change width

Tags: javascript, audio, media-player, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I have tried to find which of the plethora of tags controls the width of the mediaelement.js audio player but can't seem to work it out.

I'm assuming it's a combination of the tags that need to be edited?

I downloaded the player from the [mediaelemenjs.com](http://mediaelementjs.com/) and the CSS for it is huge.

```
<div class="fluid player">
   <audio id="player2" src="http://www.newlifedeewhy.com/media/school/2014/20140526-School-EpiLimiñana.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls></audio>
   <script>$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer();</script>
</div>
```

Here is [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/newlife77/nk66skw2) for demonstration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find the option at the [API list](http://mediaelementjs.com/#api)

```
// if the <video width> is not specified, this is the default
defaultVideoWidth: 480,
// if the <video height> is not specified, this is the default
defaultVideoHeight: 270,
// if set, overrides <video width>
videoWidth: -1,
// if set, overrides <video height>
videoHeight: -1,
// width of audio player
audioWidth: 400,
// height of audio player
audioHeight: 30,
```

eg:

```
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({audioWidth: 600});
```

Comment: That's helped a bit. The volume control is not being displayed with in the player boundaries though...how do I fix that?

Comment: just modify the default style:
.mejs-controls a.mejs-horizontal-volume-slider {
    width: 30px;
}